# Systemd service timeout

Tags: debian, systemd, d-bus

I am running Debian 8.11 inside a XEN Guest. In the syslog there are the following messages which get repeated every few seconds:

```
dbus[]: [system] Failed to active service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out 
systemd[]: systemd-logind.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
systemd[]: Failed to start Login Service.
systemd[]: Unit systemd-logind.service entered failed state
systemd[]: systemd-logind.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart
systemd[]: Stopping Login Service...
systemd[]: Starting Login Service...
```

I found several bug reports so I tried apt-get update && apt-get upgrade but unpacking procps always fails with

```
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
```

I also tried to just upgrade systemd but I get the same result.

Most systemctl commands will return a 'Connection timed out' message.

Running `SYSTEM_LOG_LEVEL=debug /lib/systemd/systemd-logind` returns the following:

```
... Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=Subscribe cookie=7 reply_cookie=0 errror=n/a
Failed to enable subscription: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
```

There was a power failure a few days ago, but all other guests and dom0 are running fine.

How can I fix this error?